# Sunlamp inside of a Cave

Tags: lighting, shadows

So I'm working on a scene where I need to light a city inside a cave with four sunlamps, except when I add the cave box the light gets stopped by the cave. How can I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use spotlights instead. The sun lamp is a special case where the position of it doesn't matter, only it's direction. You could possibly choose to disable shadow rays (Object properties -> Visibility -> Ray Visibility: Shadow) but I doubt that you'll get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Do you know of any way I can turn them into spotlights without losing the settings the sunlamps provide? Playing around with them is quite tedious since the scene is a bit too big for my computer :/

Comment: There isn't really a clear path to convert sun to spot sadly. You could possibly calculate the size from the distance and angle and the strength based on the inverse square law and the distance. I think it's a bit too messy and it doesn't give the same result even if you do.

Comment: Ohh okay, yeah it sounds like a lot of effort. I managed to get a pretty decent result by just turning the Size and the power up a lot and adjusting the positions. It doesn't look exactly the same but it does the job well enough. Again, thank you so so much for your help! I really apreciate it :)!